# How to use ServiceStack with Razor on mono

Tags: ubuntu, mono, servicestack

I've been following the rockstars razor demo code from ServiceStack and I run into an issue when attempting to run on mono.

Self host - runtime views (Razor based pages hang - basic html returned fine)

Self host - compiled views - has issues with RazorGeneratorBuildTask on mono build server.

Could I be missing a lib on the mono environment?

/var/TeamCity/work/5bead0e9f3bb7d30/Code/packages/ServiceStack.Razor.BuildTask.4.0.40/build/ServiceStack.Razor.BuildTask.targets Error executing task RazorGeneratorBuildTask: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling Razor Views and the RazorGeneratorBuildTask doesn't work on Mono. The Razor Views need to be compiled on Windows/.NET first you should then be able to run the compiled Razor Pages dll in Mono.

Comment: Thanks @mythz once again

Comment: One more if i may @mythz, in order to view the compiled view demo code on mono do I need to target a mono profile for the views project and recompile or should it work as is?

Comment: @MikeW should work as-is, it's how we're doing it for [ServiceStack.Gap](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap), i.e. compile on Windows, run on mono cross-platform.

Comment: Cheers @mythz, copied the exe's for Gap to a fresh mono'd 14.04 and get win32 exception (file not found) for Chat and Arg_InsufficientSpace parameter name chars for Bench .. I'll try another flavour of linux and see how it goes

Comment: still havent cracked it...I'm installing mono-complete via apt-get, copying up the self hosted chat, rockstars demos win32 file not found error.  which linux do you use to test with?

Comment: @mythz is this still the case i have my entire build on a mono box was wondering if there was a way to make this run or an alternative.

Comment: @AlfredoAlvarez Mono still can't precompile razor views however I'd strongly suggest migrating to .NET Core which is fully supported on Linux and performs and is much more reliable than Mono. We've developed a version of ServiceStack's RazorFormat that uses and integrates nicer with .NET Core MVC which you can read about at http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-razor